# separating values in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I am trying to separate values in R and I am stuck. 
Let's say I have this string

```
data <- data.frame(Variable = "2018 Hyundai Sonata VALUE Edition Limited 2.0")
```

Here's what I am looking for: "2018", "Hyundai", "Sonata", "VALUE Edition Limited 2.0"

Here's what I did:

```
library(tidyr)
fixed <- data %>%
    separate(Variable, into = c("Year", "Make", "Model", "Trim"), sep = " ")

#   Year    Make  Model  Trim
# 1 2018 Hyundai Sonata VALUE
```

It works but cuts off after VALUE, is there a way leave the rest of the string as it is?

Comment: Reproducible example, please.

Comment: You need to add the argument `extra = "merge"` : `separate(variable, into = c("Year", "Make", "Model", "Trim"), sep = " ", extra = "merge")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. THe answer is:

```
extra = "merge"
```